# Gwt reloading is getting called multiple times

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing web application with java-gwt. In one case i need to reload the browser tab, for that i used 
  "Window.Location.reload()", but it is reloading the browser continuosly, I do not know what might be the reason, Please look into the following code:

```
String existedLoginId = (String) Offline.get(GroupCookies.grpId.getCookieName());
    String updatedLoginId = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getParameter("groupId");
    if (existedLoginId.equals(updatedLoginId)) {
        LoginInfo.setSessionId(Cookies.getCookie(GroupCookies.dsessionId.getCookieName()));         
    } else {
        **Window.Location.reload();**       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Window.Location.reload()` reloads the webpage once, as intended. The issue is that your code is being executed everytime.

If `existedLoginId.equals(updatedLoginId)` returns `false`, it will reload, then it will return `false` again, then it will reload ad nauseum.

If it is `false`, once, when it reloads, something should happen to make `existedLoginId.equals(updatedLoginId)`, otherwise you will get a infinite loop.

Comment: yes, andre, i am calling the above code before sending every request to the server, that is why it is happeing like this.thank you

Comment: @User: If your question has been answered, you should accept (and possibly upvote) the best answer. This is how we say thank you around here. Welcome to the community!